# Can chrome adjust the frame size by using the zoom feature?

Tags: html, google-chrome

[Here is an example](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_2.html)

In IE9 and chrome,press ctrl + to zoom 200%:
[image]

Is there any way to adjust the frame size by using the zoom feature?(like IE9)

**Reference:**

- [Enlarge frame size with zoom](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/PGwf6ayEq4Y)

Comment: don't you mean ...the same effect with _chrome_?

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs needs adjust the frame size by using the zoom feature,like IE9

Comment: If you could get the current zoom size in javascript, then you could perhaps do something...

Answer (score 0):

myFix.js

```js
//fix webkit browsers
if ('WebkitAppearance' in document.documentElement.style) {
    document.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (document.readyState != 'complete')
            return;

        var oldLevel = 1;
        //whether we're fixing 'rows' or 'cols'
        var checking = 'rows';
        var frameset = document.getElementById('set');
        //get the hard coded values from the html
        var values = frameset.getAttribute(checking).split(',');

        //make sure not to change any %'s or *'s
        var isPixels = new RegExp('[0-9]+');
        for (var index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
            if (isPixels.test(values[index]))
                values[index] = new Number(values[index]);
        }

        var zoomCheck = function() {
            //calculate zoom level
            var level = window.outerWidth / window.innerWidth;
            //if it hasn't changed, ignore
            if (oldLevel == level)
                return;

            var newValues = new Array(values.length);
            //copy each of the original values
            for (var index = 0; index < values.length; ++index) {
                newValues[index] = values[index];

                //fix the ones we are meant to
                if (values[index] instanceof Number)
                    newValues[index] *= level;
            }

            //apply the fix
            frameset.setAttribute(checking, newValues.join(','));
            oldLevel = level;
        };

        //periodically check
        setInterval(zoomCheck, 1000);
    };
}
```

your.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <!--your other stuff-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="myFix.js"></script>
    </head>

    <frameset id="set" rows="200,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
        <frame name="menu" src="menu_1.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="">
        <frame name="content" src="content.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize="">
    </frameset>
</html>
```